Toast Not displaying correctly when we view community on mobile but working fine on Desktop
We have built a community site (LWR) but for some reason toasts are not displaying correctly when we view it on mobile.
This is the code i am using to display the toast.
Toast.show({
    label: 'Error',
    message: ToastErrMsg,
    mode: 'dismissible',
    variant: 'error'
}, this);




Looks to me like the SLDS styling applied doesn't play well on mobile.
